# Importing Ant Design Component doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, meteor, npm, antd, meteor-react

I'm shocked over this problem I'm currently having right now. All my logic literally stopped. Something started not working, without me having changed anything. I mean I even have it on production, the identical code, but locally it started not working, out of nothing. Even when I go back to previous commits, that I'm 100% sure was working, it doesn't work.

Meteor, React, Ant-Design. Please help!

The error is: `ReferenceError: Layout is not defined`

Code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import Blaze from 'meteor/gadicc:blaze-react-component';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd';
const { Header, Content, Footer } = Layout;

class LayoutContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const { match, children } = this.props;
    const pathname = match.location.pathname;

    return (
      <Layout className="layout">
        <Header style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
          <Menu
            selectedKeys={[pathname]}
            mode="horizontal"
            style={{ lineHeight: '64px', float: 'right' }}
          >
            <Menu.Item key={'/'}>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key={'/create-a-gathering'}>
              <Link to="/create-a-gathering">Create</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
          <div className="logo" />
          <Blaze template="loginButtons" />
        </Header>
        <Content style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          {children}
        </Content>
        <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>

        </Footer>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default LayoutContainer;
```

Comment: I see similar/impossible errors sometimes and rebuild.  Delete node-modules folder.  Restart server etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have answered this long time ago, but here it goes:

As Afaq Ahmed Khan pointed out (that too) :

```
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd/lib';
```

is the answer.

I guess babel in two packages conflict with each other and thus `'/lib'` to root `'/'` alias doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

this is a reported antd issue here [Reference Error: Layout not defined](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/4618)

an easy way to solve this is importing layout like this

```
 import Layout from 'antd/lib/layout'
```

or you can also sort it out by updating antd version to "^3.2.2" or up

Answer (score 0):

That can be resolved by deleting node-modules folder then rebuilding the whole project.

Comment: I've tried that too. I've tried to pull completely from remote repo and build in another directory. Still didn't work.